# Bash script - error while saving variable from input file

Tags: mysql, bash

I have the following script i´m building :

```
#/bin/bash -xv
echo "Pls enter your filename with the values:"
read filename
inputfile="$filename"
sc=$(mysql -uuser -ppass db -s -N -e" select min(id) from tableY where paramx= 12 and char_length(address_range) < 246;")
echo $sc
cat $inputfile | while read address_range orig_address_range; do
    row=$address_range
    raw=$(echo "select address_range from tableY where paramx= 12 and id = '$sc';") 
    line=$(echo $raw)
    echo $line
    rowadd=$row"|"$raw
    echo $rowadd
    ((sc++))    
done | mysql -uuser -ppass db;
```

So, the objective of this code would be :

- Give a file with values like this - ^11223344$ ^1[0-9]{10}$ where the "^11223344$" is the address_range
- Check from the tableY and paramx which is the first entry from address_range is smaller than 246 in size so i can add a new value to it after a pipe character ("|")
- Add copy the content of the entry found and add to it the new value

Ideally i would have something like this in the end : ^1111111$|^22222$|^33333333$|^44444444$|^5555555$

So my main issue is when running the code above i get the following result :

```
Pls enter your filename with the values:
Test
861
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '^11223344$
select address_range from tableY where paramx= 12 and id = '861'' at line 1
```

So the value i had on the file "Test" is ^11223344$ ^1[0-9]{10}$ so i can see it´s getting the correct value but for some reason it´s passing an error and not joining the two components.

Even if i run just the "row" part, without trying to joining them i have a similar error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '^11223344$' at line 1
```

Sorry for the long text, if it´s confusing..it´s my first time posting here but i´m really stuck here.
Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Fix your shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Other than the lack of proper quoting and useless use of `cat`, useless use of `echo` and `$( )` to cancel each other out ([shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point all of this out), it looks like each time through the loop you print `$line` (which is the same as `$raw`) and also `$rowadd` (which is the partially-accumulated expression). *All* of these get piped to `mysql`, so it sees a whole series of partially-formed results, rather than a single final statement. Try removing the `| mysql ...` from the end, so you can see what's being sent to `mysql`.

Comment: Thanks !!! That fixed a lot of small issues.

Nevertheless for some reason i had to leave the raw expression to =$(mysql -uuser -ppass db -e "select address_range from tableY  where paramx = 12 and id = '$sc';")

Now i get almost what i want  but it still passes an error : 

Pls enter your filename with the short codes:
Test
861
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'address_range
^64997$
address_range
^64997$|^11223344$' at line 1

Comment: @GordonDavisson The removal of the | mysql... and adding it to the raw expression fixed  it finally! 

Sorry for my code noobness guys and thank you !